# how to setClickListener on action in notification

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

i need to run code when pressed on action in notification
idon't want open new activity
I want to run code for  save value in sharedPrefrencess or remove notification form stat bar ...oct
i need to remove notification and save value in sharedPrefrenccess when pressed stop actions
[image: like (stop or hide floating icon) actions]
how to do this

please help me

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do what You've described in Your question, but for more sophisticated answer You would have to update Your question and add more details like Your own code.

In order to do something like you described, while creating Your notification You have to add an `Action` and a `PendingIntent` related to that action. It will create an action button for You to tap to do something. For example, You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive the tap on the action button:

ActionReceiver.java

```java
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public ActionReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor = preferences.edit();
        // ...
        // Here You do whatever is supposed to happen
        // after clicking the button on the notification
    }
}
```

And wherever You are creating the notification, You would have to call `addAction` on Your notification builder, which will add the button to Your notification:

```java
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, ActionReceiver.class);
actionIntent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOTIFICATION_ID,
                           actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                ...
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action, 
                           getString(R.string.action_name), actionPendingIntent)
                ...
                .build();
```

Also using `BroadcastReceiver` requires You to register it. You should register it in the class in which You are creating the notification with associated receiver:

```java
actionReceiver = new ActionReceiver();
registerReceiver(actionReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_NAME));
```

Comment: thank you for your solution please what the snoozeIntent object

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a leftover from some of my code, that I've copied and forgot to change (now it is edited) :D